# Android & CSS :: html pre tag is not proper in webview for all the android devices

Tags: android, css, media-queries

In my mobile app, I am showing some data in webview. this data contains html pre tag also. The text which is in the pre tag is not proper in all the devices.

For this i was using CSS media query to make it readable in all the devices.

But still it is not proper...Please help me to solve the issue..

Below is the piece of code which i am using for setting pre tag font size.

```
sStyle += "@media only screen and (max-device-width:320px){pre{font-size:5px;width: 100%;padding:0px;}}"
            + "@media only screen and (min-device-width:321px) and (max-device-width:480px){pre{font-size:25px;width: auto;padding:8px;}}"
            + "@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px){pre{font-size:15px;width: auto;padding:8px;}}"
            + "@media only screen and (min-device-width:481px) and (max-device-width:800px) {pre{font-size:30px;width: auto;padding:10px;}}"
            + "@media only screen and (min-device-width:801px) and (max-device-width:1200px){pre{font-size:30px;width: auto;padding:15px;}}"
            + "@media only screen and (min-device-width:1080px) {pre{font-size:30px;width: auto;padding:15px;}}"
            + "@media only screen and (min-device-width:1201px) and (max-device-width:3000px){pre{font-size:30px;width: auto;padding:20px;}}"
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you mean by "not proper".

Comment: I mean...in some devices pre text is coming too small(not readable) and in some other devices its bit small(livable) or just perfect....